# Remove settings bar at bottom of screen - Android

Tags: android, galaxy-tab

Whenever the menu button is pressed in an app on galaxy tabs, a settings tab comes up from the bottom that has been assigned to lead nowhere. Can this be removed so that it does not pop up?

Thanks

Comment: delete the menu file itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your menu.xml and remove the settings item.

Comment: I am a cabbage. Thanks for that. Is that the easiest answer you have ever had to give? ^^ Thanks